# How can I default a time in a date_time field for an Excel upload

Tags: acumatica

I've added the Excel upload feature to the Details section of the Employee Time Card screen (EP305000).  This works fine, but if the 'Time' field (which is actually date_time, but I can't find that in the DAC - only 'Date') isn't specified in the upload, it defaults to midnight (12:00 AM).  I want this to default to 8:00 AM, but I'm not sure how to do this, since the field is actually a date.  It doesn't seem like I can just use [PXDefault] or anything simple like that.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks...

Comment: EPTimeCardDetail inherits from PMTimeActivity which contains the Date field. Time isn't a field, it's a convention used in project editor to indicate that you want the datetime object displayed in time format. The date field is a datetime (not date) and should be initialized in a similar format as it is initialized in database ex: 2015-06-01 13:00:00.000. There's likely an issue with the code that assign the Date value.

Comment: So - do you have any idea of how what I want might be accomplished?  Or is this not doable?...

Comment: Nevermind - I think I figured it out.

Comment: Without seeing the code which assigned the date time value I had no idea, which is why I only gave general information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with, using the 'RowInserted' event:

```
    protected void EPTimeCardDetail_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        var eptcd = (EPTimecardDetail)e.Row;
        DateTime theDate = (DateTime)eptcd.Date;

        DateTime MyDate = new DateTime(theDate.Year, theDate.Month, theDate.Day, 8, 0, 0);
        eptcd.Date = MyDate;

    }
```